# a conceptual question on markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose $\{X_n,n\ge 0\}$ and $\{Y_n,n\ge0\}$ are two independent discrete-time markov chains (DTMC) with state space $S=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. Prove or give a counterexample to:

$\{X_n+Y_n,n\ge 0\}$ is also a DTMC.

Comment: The counterexample given in the accepted answer to the duplicated question doesn't have state space $S$ for both Markov chains, but it can readily be adapted.